# Longtabu total width, fixed left margin

Tags: margins, longtable, geometry, tabu, fullwidth

I'm trying to make a `longtabu` that is wider than the `textwidth` at a certain moment. I've tried different things always ending up with a different problem:

First possibility:
If I use the `adjustwidth` environment the longtabu does not align correctly. The left margin stays fixed and the right margin gets out of the page. This in contrast, if I do the exact same thing to make a `tabu`(instead of `longtabu`), it works perfectly. I think using the `adjustwidth` is the best way to go, but I can't manage to get it working.

Second possibility:
I've found a solution using the `fullwidth` package. That package does the trick, but using endhead and endfirsthead is completely ignored. So it does not help me either, because I need that.

Final possibility:
Using the `geometry` package does the trick, but that package adds a pagebreak when I start using it, I can't have that. It has to be directly under some text, which has a narrower `textwidth`.

Cheers.

I add a little example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\section{This is the original textwidth.}
\lipsum[1]

\section{This is the width I need for my longtabu}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}
    \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {*{13}{|X[l]} |}
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
   \end{tabu}
\end{adjustwidth}

\section{This is what happens}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}
    \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {*{13}{|X[l]} |}
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    \end{longtabu}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The document preamble? Or where?

Comment: It does not work properly. If I do the following only the first column is properly moved: 
`\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth { @{\hspace{-5cm}} *{13}{X[l]}}`

Acutally it is clear that it just interprets the hspace for the first column, not for the table itself.

Comment: still same problem as with the adjustwidth environment, left margin stays fixed

Comment: questions should always have a complete small example document that shows the problem, please add one to your question, it makes things a lot easier to test/discus!

Comment: I added an example to the main question.

Comment: I deleted earlier comments tabu doesn't work quite as I expected (not for the first time:) may look later

Comment: oh, over a year later, sorry:-) see answer below

Answer (score 3):

`longtable` lets you set the left and right margins but unfortunately the `tabu` wrapper around `longtable` always passes in an optional argument which sets the margins to `0pt` or `\fill` depending on the `lcr` alignment.

So for `longtabu` as well as setting the margins to `-1in` you need to patch `tabu` not to default `c` alignment (which would reset them back to `\fill`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\section{This is the original textwidth.}
\lipsum[1]

\setlength\LTleft{-1in}
\setlength\LTright{-1in}
\section{This is the width I need for my longtabu}


\noindent\kern-1in X \dotfill X\kern-1in\mbox{}



\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\tabu@setup{\def\tabu@aligndefault{x}}
\makeatother

    \begin{longtabu} to \dimexpr\linewidth+0in\relax  {*{13}{|X[l]} |}
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    \end{longtabu}


\end{document}
```